# Border around graph

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot, neato

I would like to create an border around the graph which is getting generated with nop2 engine.

```
digraph {
  a[pos="0,0!"]
  b[pos="100,0!"]
  a -> b
}
```

This gets translated into this :

[image]

which does not have an border around it. How can we generate an thick border around the whole graph?

I tried using clusters but they are not supported in neato. So, no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a **gvpr** (https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpr.1.pdf) program that will add a periphery to a (root) graph.  It does so by adding a rectangular node that is the size of the *bounding box* (the **bb** attribute), and then expanding the **bb** value.
Her is a command line:
`dot -Knop2 myfile.gv |gvpr -cf addP.gvpr | dot -Knop2 -Tpng >myfile.png`

Save this as addP.gvpr

```
/*
  add a periphery around a graph, by way of a large node (bb-sized)
*/
BEG_G {
  double   llx, lly, urx, ury, dx, dy, Margin;
  string   BB;
  graph_t  aG;
  node_t   aN;
  Margin=8;
  BB=$G.bb;
  sscanf ($G.bb, "%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf", &llx, &lly, &urx, &ury);
  llx-=Margin;
  lly-=Margin;
  urx+=Margin;
  ury+=Margin;
  $G.bb=(string)llx + "," + (string)lly + " " + (string)urx + "," + (string)ury;

  aN=node($G,"_____surround");
  aN.pos=(string)(llx+((urx-llx)/2)) + "," + (string)(lly+((ury-lly)/2));
  aN.width=(urx-llx)/72;
  aN.height=(ury-lly)/72;
  aN.shape="rect";
  aN.label="";
  aN.penwidth=4;
  aN.style="solid"  // not filled
}
```

Comment: Hey, much thanks for the discussion and sharing your valuable inputs. It worked. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**neato** will honor any clusters that have been (correctly) positioned by others, but fails to position clusters if left to its own.

If you can use the **fdp** engine instead of **nop2**/**neato**,
use this command line: `fdp -s myfile.gv -Tpng >myfile.png` and the following alteration to your input:

```
digraph {
  splines=true  // added for splined edges
  subgraph clusterX{
    graph[penwidth=4] 
    a[pos="0,0!"]
    b[pos="100,0!"]
    c[pos="200,0!"]  // for splined edge
    a -> b
    a -> c
  }
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Hi @sroush, Thank you for the reply. However, I have certain dependencies on nop2, so, would not like to move away from that.

Comment: Does this work? fdp -s myfile.gv | dot -Knop2-Tpng >myfile.png

Comment: Nope. The question I posed was a snapshot of the problem. In my project, splines are used quite a lot. And fdp does not honor them as well.

Comment: I believe that both **fdp** and **neato** use the same edge/spline layout routines.  Please enhance your request example to more completely show your requirements

Comment: No, I don't think that's correct. fdp and neato uses different engines altogether. I just tried fdp on my dot file and it completely messed up the graph generated.

Comment: Can't we create a background node with some specific size and then all other nodes comes on top of that node.

Comment: Yes, **fdp** and **neato** use very different *node* layout routines, but you seem to be  pinning the node locations to override those routines.  I believe the *edge* layout routines are the same, or nearly the same.  Please provide some version of your file that was handled differently by the two engines.

Comment: You can add a node or cluster of a specific size to do what you want, but you need to determine the size based on the layout of all the nodes, edges, and clusters.  Is this a one-time need or on-going?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yes., this is one-time need and I know the sizes already of the layout.